# Java Android - IllegalStateException, cannot instantiate httpost

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am fairly new to Android and Java, my code below is through an `IllegalStateException`.  By placing print log statements I have determined that the code makes it to the line:

```
 "HttpPost post = new HttpPost(string+params)" (makes it to "Point 1")
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting an error. The URL sent to HttpPost is valid.

Note, I have tried using the commented out HttpGet line instead and have the same error.

```
public String ReadQuery(String SQL)
    {

        String host = "http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~dyel-net/readquery.php";


        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try
        {



        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(host);
        httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
        Log.w("DEBUGGING PRINT", "point 1");
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", username));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", password));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sql", SQL));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        Log.w("DEBUGGING PRINT", "point 2");
        Log.w("DEBUGGING PRINT", httpPost.getURI().toString());
        Log.w("DEBUGGING PRINT", httpPost.getEntity().toString());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.w("DEBUGGING PRINT", "point 3");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Log.w("DEBUGGING PRINT", "point 4");
        String htmlResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.w("DEBUGGING PRINT", "point 5");
        return htmlResponse;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "ERROR";
```

My error:

> 10-21 13:39:09.472: W/DEBUGGING PRINT(866): point 1 10-21
>   13:39:09.582: W/DEBUGGING PRINT(866): point 2 10-21 13:39:09.582:
>   W/DEBUGGING PRINT(866):
>   http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~dyel-net/readquery.php? 10-21
>   13:39:09.616: W/DEBUGGING PRINT(866):
>   org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams@4186af10 10-21 13:39:22.792:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(866): Shutting down VM 10-21 13:39:22.802:
>   W/dalvikvm(866): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x41465700) 10-21 13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 10-21 13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity 10-21 13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633) 10-21 13:39:23.713:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(866):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 10-21 13:39:23.713:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(866):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 10-21
>   13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 10-21
>   13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 10-21
>   13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-21 13:39:23.713:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(866):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 10-21
>   13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-21
>   13:39:23.713: E/AndroidRuntime(866):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-21 13:39:23.713:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(866):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

Comment: Use the debugger and add a watch for "host+params" and see if its what you expect it to be.

Comment: The url is correct, it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(host+params);
        //HttpGet get = new HttpGet(host+params);
```

This is not the correct way to make a POST request using HttpClient. HTTP GET request and HTTP POST request works differently. In HTTP GET request you can send data as a part of url e.g., `http://mysite.com?feild1=data1&feild2=data2` but, HTTP POST request has a `request message body` where you need to write your data to the server.

Try the following code:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://targethost/login");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", username));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", password));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sql", SQL));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: I am still getting an error at "HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);", could not execute method of the activity.

Comment: I am repeatedly asking you the question. What error, what messages it shows ?

Comment: Sorry, I am having connection issues.  I updated the main post with the error log.

Comment: @TheDude, did you insert the url with a `"http://"` at the beginning? And you might want to add a Header too. after creating httpPost instance, put the code `httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "text/plain")`;

Comment: My url does contain http:// at the beginning.  I added your header and I am getting the same result.

Comment: I am trying to request http://.../.../readquery.php?user=...&pw=...&sql=... I have host being http://.../.../readquery.php?, is this incorrect?

Comment: yes. Try with putting the url: `http://.../.../readquery.php` in the HttpPost(url) and then add those field as i have shown in my answer

Comment: It still does not work.  Is there any way I could directly just send a whole url and get the result?

Comment: I updated my main post with exactly what I have in the method.

Comment: @TheDude, can you give me the form link which contains the action url and input field ? Are you sure the form uses GET or POST as it's action method ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39683/discussion-between-the-dude-and-sage)